# code or csv file not allowing upload

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlimport

either a issue with the code or csv is causing trouble for the import. Anything that could be a problem with the code, or with the csv?

When i run the script i get a default messeage of : CSV File not readable

This works for 5 out of the 15 files and cannot see an obvious issue or solution.

http://www.dodgejeffgen.org/gs/issue1.csv

```
<?php  

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
ini_set('post_max_size', '128M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '128M');

function clean($link, $str, $default ='') {
    if (!isset($str)) $str = $default;
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
}

$host_name  = "some host";
$database   = "some db";
$user_name  = "some user";
$password   = "some pass";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); } else {}                       

$lines = $value1 = $value2 = $data = 0;

if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //print_r($data).'<br />';
        if ($data[0]) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`name`, `reference`) VALUES ('".clean($connect, $data[0])."','".clean($connect, $data[1])."')";
            //echo $sql.'<br />';
            if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) { } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connect); }
           $lines++;
       }
    }
    echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br>";
    echo "Found a total of ".$lines." records in this csv file.<br />"; 
} else { echo 'CSV File not readable.<br />';}

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: no not yet ..... prefer to stay in insert ... the csv file is the trouble but don't know where

Comment: Error Message ::MySQL server has gone awayArray ( [0] => Dornbusch, Johanna Fritsch [1] => 7/31/1961, Death*, 1950-94 D V1, pg 239 ) Error: INSERT INTO `articles` (`name`, `reference`) VALUES ('Dornbusch, Johanna Fritsch','7/31/1961, Death*, 1950-94 D V1, pg 239')

Comment: It seems you have set very short timeout and larger files failed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. Just upload your csv file to some location on your server and run the following mysql query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/csv_file.csv' INTO TABLE articles 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
(@col1,@col2) set `name`=TRIM(@col1),`reference`=TRIM(@col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` like Indra Kumar S reccomends. You may be able to load it into a temporary table (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`), then use mysql queries to distribute that data to whatever permanent tables you store the data in.

Remember in addition to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` there is also `FIELDS ESCAPED BY`, plus other options. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

The cool thing about loading into MySQL first is you that you can use MySQL, sometimes with PHP's help, to do a lot of data cleaning. MySQL should do a pretty good job of trimming edges, but you might prefer selecting out to PHP and then writing back into MySQL for more complex cleaning, like removing non-breaking spaces, extra spaces inside of strings, or non-ASCII characters.

When I did something like this, I think I did one run through the CSV to determine data types for each column (`varchar`, `int`, `decimal`, `text`, `datetime`), and then created the temporary table with matching datatypes, and the did `LOAD DATA INFILE` to that table.